# Is it possible to use a handheld as a main development platform?

Tags: mobile

After reading [this](http://ycombinator.com/rfs5.html) post and some derivative publications (ddotdash.com) I wonder whether it is possible to use a handheld as a main platform for development of web applications for mobile web browsers.

For web development I use a rather common set of tools: Cheap netbook, Ubuntu 9.10, Ruby on Rails, VIM, GIT. I think it is possible to use all of those on Nokia n900 due to the fact that it has Maemo OS on it which is based on Debian (all debs are possible to install and you can always compile problematic debs from source).

Nevertheless, I am concerned with 3 problems:

1. Display size. I have 1280x800 resolution on my netbook and it is convenient for me to have Terminator (multiple consoles), VIM, file browser, Firefox and some PDF books opened at the same time. I wonder if it would be possible to use all these apps on 800px horizontal resolution.
2. Computing power: Via Nano (or Atom) processor does not distinct dramatically from that on Nokia n900 (at least in MHz), however I wonder if 256+768(virtual) memory on Nokia will be enough for my work (I have 3 GB now on the netbook).
3. Keyboard. Frankly it is not a problem due to the fact that I have Nokia su-8w bluetooth keyboard that is comfortable enough for touch typing. However it is interesting to read some comments on this problem. [Edit]: Bluetooth keyboard is not so comfortable - a developer has to dispose a handheld on the keyboard and it is not easy to look at the small screen from such rather big distance (keyboard can be placed on a table or on the knees only).

Having solutions for the problems mentioned above, I will have an opportunity to exploit all the wonderful advantages of the mobile development platforms, such as:

- work from anywhere (it is important for me);
- develop for the same form-factor that is used by the developer and intended users both;
- pocket-size working tool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may well be *possible* - the question is how much energy you'll expend compensating for all the restrictions. It's like developing in Notepad: possible, but not a pleasant experience.

I develop a *bit* on my netbook too, and it's okay - but I wouldn't want to do it all day.

It's certainly quite *cool* to be able to develop on a handheld device, but I don't think it's really practical for significant amounts of code. If this is for your own personal pleasure and you think the benefits outweigh the costs, that's one thing - but I wouldn't do it for commercial apps.